# symfony 3 and mongodb bundle, findBy not fetching every information

Tags: mongodb, symfony

I have a problem. 
COde:

```
$mediaRepo = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Media');
    $media = $mediaRepo->findBy(['accountId' => $account->getId()]);

    foreach ($media AS $m) {
        echo $m->getMediaSource();
    }
```

Foreach loop is being executed 24 times, as expected since I have 24 documents in my mongo db collection. The problem is that I can only use getId and getAccountId, other values are always null, but documents in my collection have values, there's no field with NULL value.

Document looks like this
*id*
accountId int
mediaSource string
isVideo bool
lastUpdate date

Symfony 3, bundle and odm:

```
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "~1.0",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "@dev"
```

Comment: any help? can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

bin/console cache:clear did the magic

Comment: When enough time has passed you should mark this as the accepted answer.  If possible, i would post any details about why it solved the problem as well to make it a better answer.